# Вопрос про локальные переменные

Tags: c++, visual-studio, переменные

Добрый день. В качестве компилятора использую VS. Недавно у меня появился вопрос, в котором я хотел узнать, почему не работает программа. Объяснили мне так, что я просто забыл переменную инициализировать (Мне нужен был ноль). Получается, локальные переменные компилятор не инициализирует даже нулём? И ещё вопрос по этой же теме: В дебаггере я смотрел значения каждой переменной при первой итерации. И моя неинициализированная переменная, как сказал компилятор, в какой-то момент приняла загробное значение (Типа заоблачного, но в минусе). Это у него такой способ сказать об ошибке? Вот.

Comment: @PavelKass какого типа была переменная, принявшая "загробное" значение?

Comment: @KonstantinLes int.

Comment: Загробное - это, видимо, очень большое по модулю. Если это так, то в данном Вам ответе всё объяснено.

Comment: Кстати, если вы посмотрите на «загробное значение» в hex-режиме, вы скорее всего увидите что-то интересное.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да. Компилятор не инициализирует простые типы. Значение, которое у Вас появилось при дебагинге - это просто мусор, который до этого находился в памяти. Компилятор выделил память под Вашу переменную из свободной области. А в ней был мусор, оставшийся от предыдущих переменных, данных и т.п. Несколько иначе дело обстоит со сложными типами. Они могут быть инициализированы. В целом же, правильным/хорошим тоном считается обязательная инициализация переменных. Даже если Вам лень это делать - приучите себя.

Comment: Начало ответа хорошее, а конец так себе. Переменные типов с пользовательскими конструкторами по умолчанию совершенно не обязательно инициализировать специально.

Comment: @SergeyA А разве я не написал, что дело со сложными типами обстоит иначе, чем с простыми? Или Вы имеете ввиду, что необязательно инициализировать скажем какой-нибудь класс с конструктором? Так соглашусь только в том плане, что это если Вам известно, что там есть конструктор, который проведет инициализцию. Это можно еще говорить о стандартных классах. Но вот если у Вас будет `кот в мешке` (чужая библиотека) или, например, как автор топика, составит такой код класса, где его переменные не будут инициализированы, а потом использует его? Поэтому я и написал про хороший тон.

Comment: А как ты планируешь инициализировать класс с дефолтеным конструктором? Приведи код.

Comment: @SergeyA Проверьте простейший пример у себя в компиляторе (хотя я думаю, что Вы и без проверки поймете) и поймете почему я за обязательную инициализацию :)

class user
{
 public:
  user(){}
  user(int i){init=i;}
  int init;
};
int main()
{
 user u;
 std::cout << u.init;
 return 0;
}

Comment: @SergeyA Просто также как автор объявил переменную без ее инициализации, также он создаст и объект класса, где инициализации переменной, которую он собирается использовать, не произойдет.

Comment: Это все о чем? Вот есть, например, `std::vector` и его десяток конструкторов. Ты говоришь, что я никогда не должен делать `std::vector<int> vec;`?

Comment: @SergeyA Нет. Вот сейчас я говорю о том, что Вы невнимательно прочитали мой первый комментарий на Ваше замечание. Поэтому повторюсь... `...то там есть конструктор, который проведет инициализцию. Это можно еще говорить` **о стандартных классах**. `Но вот если у Вас будет кот в мешке...`  И Вы сейчас как раз о стандартном классе и говорите. А в то же время в своем первом комментарии Вы писали о переменных с пользовательскими конструкторами.

Comment: а я бы ещё поспорил что нужно сразу инииализировать переменную, иногда это только лишняя трата времени.

Answer (score 1):

Да, компилятор никак не инициализирует подобные переменные. Т. е. в них окажется мусор.

Visual studio в режиме отладки записывает особое значение отрицательное, с большим количеством букв `C` в шестнадцатеричной записи, а так же роняет программу при попытке обращения к неинициализированной переменной. Разумеется, это происходит только в debug'е, при компиляции в релизе подобного поведения не будет.